# Swfit 3.1: Enum and its ghostly .init(rawValue:)

Tags: swift, enums, compiler-errors

([a bug report regarding this issue has been filed on swift.org](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-4819))

Suppose you have defined an enum outside of a class in which you want to use it in a map function that returns a string for a static constant:

```
public enum SoundCatMakes : Int{
    case meow = 0, meoww, nyan, thrr, rawr, count
}

public class Nekko{
  static let sayHi : String = [Int](0..<SoundCatMakes.count.rawValue).map{
      String(describing: SoundCatMakes.init(rawValue: $0)!) 
  }.joined(separator: ",")
}
```

This works perfectly fine. It passes the compiler with no errors. But if you change the order of definitions for the enum and the class the compiler would complain that the enum does not have member `init`:

[image]

Looks like it has to do with the [failable](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html) nature of the initializer for `Swift.RawRepresentable`.

Now that the ordering matter, we can run into real problem when we have the class and enum in different files and the Swift compiler just decides to process the file containing the class definition before the file containing the enum definition (which was what I encountered in my project).

How does one go about resolving this problem (other than having both enum and class definitions in the same file)?

### Fun Fact

One would run into the same error in this scenario as well:

```
public enum SoundCatMakes : Int{
    case meow = 0, meoww, nyan, thrr, rawr, count
}


public class Nekko{
    let sayHi = SoundCatMakes.init(rawValue: 0)! // error: type 'SoundCatMakes' has no member 'init'

}
```

But the error disappears when type inference is turned off:

```
public enum SoundCatMakes : Int{
    case meow = 0, meoww, nyan, thrr, rawr, count
}


public class Nekko{
    let sayHi : SoundCatMakes = SoundCatMakes.init(rawValue: 0)! // and now the compiler is cool with this

}
```

However, this trick didn't work for the above problem:

```
public class Nekko{
    static let sayHi : String = [Int](0..<SoundCatMakes.count.rawValue).map{
        let sound : SoundCatMakes = SoundCatMakes.init(rawValue: $0)! //still got the same error..
        String(describing: sound)
        }.joined(separator: ",")
}

public enum SoundCatMakes : Int{
    case meow = 0, meoww, nyan, thrr, rawr, count
}
```

Comment: Looks like a bug (possibly related to [this](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3183)) – you should [file a bug report](https://bugs.swift.org). Removing `.init` also allows it to compile.

Comment: @Hamish yeah. Good point. Removing `.init` does allow scenario 2 (under Fun Fact) to compile but not scenario 1 with the ordering.

Comment: Also works with scenario 1 for me. As a side note, you should avoid testing Swift behaviour in playgrounds – they're really buggy and unreliable. Test in a full project instead.

Comment: @Hamish oh cool. Yeah it works for me now (oops didn't wait for playground to finish loading just now). Thanks man you've solved this problem for me!

Comment: @Hamish I have been writing `.init` explicitly for enum so regularly that it just didn't occur to me it can be abridged into `ENUM(...)` similar to that of init for classes until you mentioned it. Thanks. Kudos to you. You should add that as an answer.